# Unable to insert figure with a given document class

Tags: graphics, templates

I was told to make a document with a given template. That uses a class called `jps-cp`. Using this class I am unable to insert any figures. When `article` class is used I can insert figures using `\includegraphics`. Can anybody tell what could be the problem?

```
%\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\documentclass{jps-cp}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

To explain the matter-antimatter asymmetry observed in the universe, must be satisfied \cite{c1}.

\begin{figure}[tbh]
\includegraphics{mrec.eps}
\caption{You can embed figures }
\end{figure}


\section{Conclusion}
In summary, the  first study of baryon number violation is done.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As `jps-cp` is not a standard class you could add a link to it, if possible. Also add the error message. Maybe `jps-cp` does not load something that is loaded by `article` or there is some conflict?

Comment: The template can be found from here https://journals.jps.jp/page/jpscp/authors. I am using TexMaker in Ubuntu. There is no error message, it's compiling successfully. Also, the caption is coming but no plots. Figure fromat I have tried in eps, png also pdf. One can debug with any figure.

Comment: Also another thing, figures are insertable with the same template by TeXshop in MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the implicit workflow.

The `jps-cp` class, in contravention to the suggested best practice listed in the documentation for the `graphicx` package, hard codes a driver. You find in it

```
\RequirePackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```

which specifies using the `dvipdfmx` driver. Which means that if you compile your document, which uses the `jps-cp` class, using `pdflatex`, you will not see the included image. But if you compile it using the two-step process

```
latex file.tex 
dvipdfmx  file.dvi
```

the image will now appear. I bet if you look under the "working" installation of TeXShop you will find that it does the two step process, while TeXMaker just calls pdflatex.

Comment: Thank You so much! It works.